# Disabling OpenSSO default Web Services

Tags: openam, opensso

How can i disable OpenSSO Web Services which are provided by default?

Currently my application's OpenSSO can be accessed by the following URL's:

```
http://host_machine.domain:8080/opensso/identityservices/IdentityServices

http://host_machine.domain:8080/opensso/identityservices?WSDL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only be done by tweaking web.xml

Have you tried to remove the following servlet-mappings?

IdentityServices
    /identityservices/
  
  
    *IdentityServicesHandler
    /identity/*

Sidenote: If you're using newer agents they might not work anymore.

-Bernhard

Comment: Whwn i am commenting the servlet-mappings authentication is not working, Error given is Default datastore Provider is unavailable

Answer (score 0):

Commented only this part in web.xml and it worked!!!

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>IdentityServices</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/identityservices/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```